# What is Predecessor of an element in an array? How do I find it?

Tags: c++, arrays

I tried to Google but in vain.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ arrays are stored in contiguous memory.

This means that if you have an element `x` and you know that it's inside an array and that it's not the first element of the array, then then previous one is

```
*(&x - 1)
```

i.e. the element pointed by the address of `x` after we subtract 1 (note that this works because pointer arithmetic in C++ considers element size, so `&x - 1` is not point to the byte before, but to the element before).

Comment: As we may overload `operator&`, we have to use `std::addressof`.

Comment: @Jarod42: who redefines `operator&` is also probably going to have a `#define else` in the code so there are going to be problems anyway :-)